# Looping through Comboboxes on form and clearing datasource

Tags: combobox, datasource

I'm having some trouble looping through the comboboxes on my form and to clear the data sources (using VB.net in Visual Studio 2017)

the code I have so far is this:

==============================

```
    For Each c As Control In Me.Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox)()
        If c.Name IsNot Control.Name Then c.datasource = Nothing
    Next
```

==============================

However, get the error " 'DataSource' is not a member of 'control' "

The "Control" is a variable passed to the sub

====================

```
Public Sub Item_Select(ByRef Field As String, ByRef Control As Control)
```

====================

and is called like this

==================

```
Dim Control1 As Control = ComboBox2
Item_Select("Last_Name", Control1)
```

==================

The datasource is an SQL table

Could anyone point me in the right direction? I don't seem to be getting the right search terms in google for a workable solution!

Thanks so much in advance, and apologies if this post is inappropriate (i have read the guide!)

Answer (score 0):

This woks as a solution!

```
For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
              If TypeOf c Is ComboBox Then
                  Dim ctrl = DirectCast(c, ComboBox)
                  ctrl.DataSource = Nothing
              End If
Next
```